# Python regex for markdown heading

Tags: python, regex

I need regex which would match .md files headings. For example:

# Heading 1

## heading 2 (sometext in parentheses)

###Heading 3

But it should not match some cases:

1. [Some internal link](

#foo)

2. [Some internal link](

   #foo)
3. [Some internal link](

#foo

)

I try something like this:

```
heading_regex = re.compile(r'^(#{1,6}[^\n(](?!\(\n)\(?[^\n](?!\n\)).+)$', flags=re.M)

heading_regex = re.compile(r'^(#{1,6}.+(?!\(\n)|(?!\n\))|(?!\)))$', flags=re.M)
```

But i can't succeed.

Please give me some tips or solution.

Comment: There are markdown parsers for Python. Use one of them.

Comment: @Tomalak, but i don't need markdown parser. I need correct regex.

Comment: Use the best trick ever, `(?m)(\[[^][]*]\([^()]*\))|^#.*`, make sure you check if Group 1 matched, and if it did, discard the match, else process the match. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cVCCSg/1)

Comment: Hm, try [this Python code](https://ideone.com/Ca60QA)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, sorry but it seems this code does not work. And re.sub() is used.

Comment: That code works. What do you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, then i don't understand how it works. I need compiled regex for further usage.

Comment: Then, there is no regex that will help you. Consider using existing markdown engines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, please could you shortly explain why there is not such regex ? How do you know it ?